# displaying photo?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to do this in an alert box only to find out that I can't now. I cannot manage to get this to display at all. Instead of the variable I get `[object HTMLImageElement]`. I am missing something but what is it?

```
function joePic(){
    var joe_fat = new Image;
    joe_fat.src = "pic1.jpg";
    document.getElementById('photo').innerHTML = joe_fat;
}
```

```
<input type="button" value="Click here it find out" name="joePhoto" onclick="joePic()" 
height="150" width="150" />
```

Comment: I'd rather write this in HTML/CSS (i.e. with a fixed positioned div element) and toggle the visibility with JS. Does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're trying to assign an `Image` as HTML, but it's not HTML. It's an `Image`.

You have two options:

1. Append `joe_fat` into the `#photo` element using the proper DOM function (which is `appendChild`) instead of pretending it's a string of HTML:

   ```
   function joePic() {
       var joe_fat = new Image;
       joe_fat.src = "pic1.jpg";

       var photoElm = document.getElementById('photo');
       photoElm.innerHTML = '';        // clear target first
       photoElm.appendChild(joe_fat);  // now add image
   }
   ```
2. Get rid of the `Image` object and actually do present a string of HTML instead:

   ```
   function joePic() {
      document.getElementById('photo').innerHTML = '<img src="pic1.jpg" />";
   }
   ```

Comment: I went with the second choice, but from what I read here I need to brush up on this append child business.

Answer (score 0):

Use `appendChild()` instead of `innerHTML`:

```
function joePic(){
  var joe_fat = new Image;
  joe_fat.src = "pic1.jpg";
  document.getElementById('photo').appendChild(joe_fat);
}
```

To do this via `innerHTML` (which isn't the preferred method), you would need to set `#photo`'s `innerHTML` property to be the actual `<img>` markup, as in:

```
document.getElementById('photo').innerHTML = "<img src='pic1.jpg' alt='alttext' />";
```

This would overwrite any existing contents of `#photo`.  The correct method is to use `appendChild()` to manipulate the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

```
function joePic() {
    var joe_fat = new Image();
    joe_fat.src = "pic1.jpg";
    document.getElementById('photo').appendChild(joe_fat);
}
```